# helllo everybody ,i always get the same problem with this could someone help me?

Tags: google-apps-script, automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBLMC.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAwiu.png)

```
function myFunction() {
  //Über welchem Arbeitsblatt soll gearbeitet werden
  const KUNDENSHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("KUNDENSHEET");
  //Daten aus Zeile einlesen
  var row = getRow();
  var name = KUNDENSHEET.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
 
  var kundeSeit = KUNDENSHEET.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  var bestellwert = KUNDENSHEET.getRange(row, 7).getValue();

  console.log(name, vorname, ort, strasseNummer, kundeSeit, bestellwert);
}

function getRow() {
  var row = Browser.inputBox('Welcher Kunde', 'Welcher Kunde ist das?', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  return row;
}




08:24:26    Hinweis Ausführung begonnen
08:24:34    Fehler  
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')
myFunction  @ Code.gs:6
```

i wanted to see the row that i select from Browserinput.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "KUNDENSHEET" is your spreadsheet name. In the below line, you need to pass sheet name but you are passing the spreadsheet name which is why KUNDENSHEET variable is null.

```
 const KUNDENSHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("KUNDENSHEET");
```

For eg, in the below image, spreadsheet name is "KUNDENSHEET" but the sheet name is "Sheet1". So your statement should be as below.

```
 const KUNDENSHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```

[image]

Comment: i changed the spreadname to sheet1 and i also added changed to this:                                                        const KUNDENSHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");  at the end the sheet opens iand i give the numer to browser input and resul is like this :
Ausführungsprotokoll
10:47:06 Hinweis Ausführung begonnen
10:47:17 Hinweis Ausführung abgeschlossen  and that doesnt show the line

Comment: Sorry, the error msg is in a language which I don't understand. Can you translate it?